# Trim a string between two delimiters

Tags: regex

I have a number string, for example 14569927-4332-119-02.
I would like to trim this from the first '-' delimiter to the next '-' delimiter.
The result let be only: '4332'.

I tried this regex: (^-[0-9]) but I it's not perfect.

How could I trim this '4332' from the string?

Thank you & have a nice weekend!

Comment: How is this related to SAP or ABAP after all?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in ABAP? If so, you may be a little disappointed to find that the ABAP regex engine does not support limiting greedy selection (unless that's been added in the latest release). You may be better off using FIND to find the offset of the first two '-' or something like that. Not nice.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about SAP and ABAP, using regex is not probably the best option - it might provide good sign of mastery for writer, but it makes the stuff no easy for readers. In ABAP you might probably resort to other options...

This would be my take:

```
data: l_var type string value '14569927-4332-119-02',
      lt_parts type standard table of string,
      l_result type string.

split l_var at '-' into table lt_parts.
read table lt_parts into l_result index 2.
if sy-subrc ne 0.
  " error handling --- not found...
endif.
```

Effectively these are two lines instead of one regex, but it is much more transparent what you are doing...

Answer (score 1):

A few options...

`awk`:

```
$ string='14569927-4332-119-02'
$ awk -F- '{print $2}' <<< "$string"
4332
```

`bash`:

```
$ string=${string%-*-*}
$ string=${string#*-}
$ echo "$string"
4332
```

`cut`:

```
$ cut -d'-' -f2 <<< "$string"
4332
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sed`:

```
$ echo "14569927-4332-119-02" | sed 's/[^\-]*\-\([^\-]*\)\-.*/\1/g'
4332
```

Comment: There seems to be a certain superfluity of escapes here, it confuses the pattern. `-` doesn't need to be escaped, not even in a character class if it's the last character. Closing brackets and parenthesis do not need to be escaped. Further, negated character classes are best followed by a possessive quantifier, so `*+` rather than just `*`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Well, if I don't escape the parentheses, `sed` bails out: `RE error: parentheses not balanced` - so it's certainly needed.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought sed used perl regex - perl doesn't require closing brackets to be escaped. Most interesting.

Comment: @BoristheSpider FYI, I'm on OS X. Maybe *another* subtle unintuitive difference (or it's just that `sed` on OS X is ancient amongst others...)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: you can use sed with two regex modes: BRE(Basic RE) and ERE(Extended RE). In BRE parenthesis and + quantifier must be escaped. In ERE (ie:`sed -E /...`) you don't need to escape them. The default mode is BRE (as in grep). Some sed implementations can use a Perl mode too.

Comment: @Boris sed is different. It doesnt take special symbols as those functional symbols but rather sees them as plain text... to make it happen, u have to escape. this includes brackets and braces